# Is there any solution for this? I am getting error message as: There's nothing here, yet. when I added the custom domain in heroku

Tags: heroku, subdomain, hosting, godaddy-api

I want to host my heroku project in custom sub-domain of one of my root domain from godaddy. But on loading after 48 hrs. I am getting this screenshot:
[image]

These are my **Heroku** configurations:

**Domain Name   :** `www.dashboard.grumpytext.com`

**DNS Target :** `cubic-iceberg-nf62brjhf5g4zt56g6kjmp4i.herokudns.com`

These are my **goDaddy** configurations:

**Type:**  `CNAME`

**Name:**  `dashboard`

**Value:**      cubic-iceberg-nf62brjhf5g4zt56g6kjmp4i.herokudns.com

**TTL:** `1 Hour`

Answer (score 0):

`www` is a subdomain by itself it is in most cases the default subdomain

the other subdomain that you have set up is `dashboard`

so you need to use `dashboard` without the `www` part so you can try just going to [https://dashboard.grumpytext.com](https://dashboard.grumpytext.com/)

and you will find your app